# Queen's gambit continuation

Tags: opening, theory, queens-gambit

I have reached this same position a number of times, what would be the most sound continuation for white?

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6
```

Two moves that come to mind are Bg5 or Nf3.

What are your thoughts and ideas behind the next move?

Comment: Those are two perfectly good moves, among others. It does not make a particle of difference which one you play. Unless you are playing at the super-grandmaster level, but in that case I wouldn't expect you to be asking that question on this site.

Comment: In this place I would choose to go Bg5 route, as it promises slight advantage for white. Nothing big, but it is really unpleasant for Black. Search material on Exchange variation of Queen's Gambit decline. You can find some really good posts on this site as well.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff you are supposed to answer in answers, not in comments

Answer (score 5):

According to Hans Berliner, correspondence chess champion, Bg5 is the best.
From his book "The System. A World Champion's Approach to Chess" he stated, and Fischer agrees, that Bg5 maintain the most amount of pressure.  Nf3 is not as good, because you has three major plans in the QGD exchange variation and only one has the knight on f3.

My opinion is that Bf4 is stronger below master level.  I like the idea of Bxb8, not having the question put to the bishop on g5, and it reduces the possibility of Bd6.  There are disadvantages to putting the bishop of f4.

The answer depends upon what type of positions you like to play.  For positional games, the knight goes to f3, for center control and kingside attacks, the knight goes to g3 via e2.

Answer (score 0):

cxd5 because it's forcing. You can develop the Bishop after e4 which further antagonises the centre and double central pawn moves are classed as tempo!

If you don't receive negative feedback on this move I would try it.

Some might call this swapping a wing pawn for a central pawn... and it half opens the King file!